# Java TimeZone and shortcuts for time-zone names issue

Tags: java, timezone

I have an linux application that presents time with time-zone in iOS-XR format:
tech system clock status local-time-string "10:16:12.523 CDT Thu Mar 21 2013"

I also see that the "CDT" shortcut is being used in the linux "zdump" output:

> zdump -v America/Havana | grep 2013
>   America/Havana  Sun Mar 10 04:59:59 2013 UTC = Sat Mar  9 23:59:59 2013 CST isdst=0 gmtoff=-18000
>   America/Havana  Sun Mar 10 05:00:00 2013 UTC = Sun Mar 10 01:00:00 2013 CDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
>   America/Havana  Sun Nov  3 04:59:59 2013 UTC = Sun Nov  3 00:59:59 2013 CDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
>   America/Havana  Sun Nov  3 05:00:00 2013 UTC = Sun Nov  3 00:00:00 2013 CST isdst=0 gmtoff=-18000

but when I run "System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CDT"));" Java command I get the GMT time zone...

1. can anybody explain what is the criteria for the short-cuts existence in the Java timeZone object?
2. where can I find an open-source code for converting time strings into "Date" objects... the current parser I'm using relays on Java Calendar, SimpleDateFormat and Date but since Java TimeZone does not recognize "CDT" it parses this string as it was a GMT time...

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> where can I find an open-source code for converting time strings into "Date" objects

Built into Java in the java.time classes.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23" )
LocalTime.parse( "14:56:00" )
LocalDateTime.parse( "2017-01-23T07:56:00" )
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-01-23T07:56:00-07:00" )
ZonedDateTime.parse( "2017-01-23T07:56:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]" )
```

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `ZoneId`

The `java.util.TimeZone` class is replaced by `java.time.ZoneId` and `java.time.ZoneOffset`. A time zone is a history of changes to a particular region’s offset-from-UTC.

There are *many* poor design decisions in the legacy java.time classes. Using the 3-4 character pseudo time zone codes is one such poor choice. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `CDT` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Instead, you should specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`.

### ISO 8601

Avoid using badly designed awkward formats such as "10:16:12.523 CDT Thu Mar 21 2013" which are hard to read by humans, difficult to parse by machine, rely on English needlessly, and make use of ambiguous (worse than useless!) pseudo time zones. Instead use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The java.time classes use these formats by default. The `ZonedDateTime` class extends the standard format by appending the continent/region time zone name in square brackets.

Examples:

- 2017-01-23
- 14:56:00
- 2017-01-23T14:56:00Z
- 2017-01-23T07:56:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

For formats other than [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Already covered many hundreds of times already, so search Stack Overflow for more info and examples.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

1) see java.util.DateFormatSymbols.getZoneStrings, it returns an array of

```
•zoneStrings[i][0] - time zone ID
•zoneStrings[i][1] - long name of zone in standard time
•zoneStrings[i][2] - short name of zone in standard time
•zoneStrings[i][3] - long name of zone in daylight saving time
```

we can use 'time zone ID' in TimeZone.getTimeZone(), the rest as SimpleDateFormat 'z' General Time Zone

2) CDT is OK for SimpleDateFormat, try

```
new SimpleDateFormat("z").parse("CDT");
```

it works

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to answer the 2nd part of your question. Try Joda-time

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html

Do let us know if it helps.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).